# Mongoose find and findById inconsistency

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm testing mongoose queries, and I found this bizarre behaviour. I have a document with `_id: "5de64b376c79643fa847e86b"`, and if I call the `findById` method the document is returned just fine. But if I call the `find` method on the collection, giving as args an array with the same ID value than nothing is returned, while I expect an array of one element being the document. To summarize:

```
mongooseModel.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5de64b376c79643fa847e86b")) // Works

mongooseModel.find({ _id: { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5de64b376c79643fa847e86b")] } }) //Doesn't work
```

What's the difference between the two, and why the second one doesn't work?

EDIT: This is kinda the code to access that method.
I define a DataSource in the ApolloServer configuration

```
const app = new ApolloServer({
...
dataSources: () => ({
    source: new SourceAPI(DocumentModel)
  })
...
});
```

where SourceAPI is the `DataSource` class and `DocumentModel` is the mongoose model.
`SourceAPI` is defined like this

```
class SourceAPI {
  async get(ids) {
    return await DocumentModel.find({
      _id: {
        $in: ids
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now, inside the GraphQL resolver I finally call the API method to get the documents, like this

```
const findResolver = () =>
  DocumentSchema.get("$findById").wrapResolve(next => async rp => {
    let ids = [];
    ids.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(rp.args._id));
    return await rp.context.dataSources.source.get(ids);
  });
```

where `DocumentSchema` is the GraphQL Schema for the Document Model generated using [`graphql-compose-mongoose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-compose-mongoose) package. The `get("$findById")` and `wrapResolve` methods are also from that package. What I do is using these methods to get the GraphQL query parameters and pass them to the API method (in this case I'm just grabbing an ID for test).

If I change the API method to something like this

```
async get(id) {
    return await DocumentModel.findById(id);
  }
```

and the resolver method to this

```
const findResolver = () =>
  DocumentSchema.get("$findById").wrapResolve(next => async rp => {
    return await rp.context.dataSources.source.get(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(rp.args._id));
  });
```

everything works

Answer (score 0):

[$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is used to find items which holds an array, but `_id` is just a JSON key/value pair. So you cannot use $in. If your object looks like this then you can use $in

```
 {
    id: [ObjectId("5de64b376c79643fa847e86b"),
         ObjectId("5de64b376c79643fa847e86b")]
 }
```

Comment: Tried to do this
`return DocumentModel.find({ _id: [mongos.Types.ObjectId(id)] });`

Same result, no documents found

Comment: Why are you using `[ ]` ?